# Why do these CSS media queries not work in Firefox? I have checked the syntax and they work everywhere else

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

I can't figure out why these don't work in Firefox. All the documentation I can find says they are correct, and that they should indeed work in this version of Firefox without issue (23.0.1).

Here is documentation from Mozilla Developer that I am following to the letter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

I've also read through two dozen other documents, but all seem to be related to earlier versions of Firefox and problems with the toolbar/viewport.

Here's the code.. Works like a charm in other browsers (had to remove opening and closing tags to get the code to show)

```
link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 5000px)" href="/css/styles_1920.css"

link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 1799px)" href="/css/styles_1024.css"
```

Here's the site (total work in progress) http://www.systematic.io/test

I've spent the last 2 weeks on stackoverflow to build this thing with no prior experience using jquery. Solved almost all of my problems except this one. Thanks to everyone who posts here so others can learn!

Comment: erm, what exactly is it that doesn't work?

Comment: Out of curiosity,are you using meta viewport tag?

Comment: You should create a minimal demo that illustrates the specific problem and explain how the problem manifests itself. Make sure you validate the HTML and CSS code. Few people are interesting in digging into a complex page (especially one that contains obvious errors, like referring to HTML documents as external stylesheets).

Comment: The site you link to works fine for me in Firefox: I see only one of the two stylesheets that have media queries being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding this in your head :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Thanks to all who replied.

The problem is it always defaults to the smaller style sheet in Firefox, it never follows the queries and just loads whatever comes last. Other browsers do not do this.

Thank you for the tip Roy. I am using the correct viewport tag in the header 
name="viewport" content="width=device-width".

It must be some kind of conflict with a jquery plugin or some other error in my code somewhere. I will do as Jukka has suggested and create a simple page to see I can get it work properly.